# Given the pitch of an image, how to calculate the GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT?

Tags: opengl

Most image library give an image as width, height, pitch and then an array pixels. OpenGL however does not take a pitch directly, instead it expects:

```
 glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, align);
 glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, row_length);
```

`row_length` is `pitch / bytes_per_pixel`, but how does one calculate the proper value for `align`?

Comment: "Most image library"? I don't know of very many that do. FreeImage does, but that's about it.

Comment: SDL, ClanLib, Gtk, Cairo, libjpeg, libpng and so on, I don't think I ever touched one that didn't use width/height/pitch/array/format outside of OpenGL. Some call it `stride` or `rowbytes` instead of `pitch`, but that's about it.

Answer (score 1):

For the vast majority of images that you'll see, you shouldn't need `GL_ROW_LENGTH`. Setting this to a non-zero value can degrade upload performance severely; only employ it when you absolutely *need* it.

For most images, the pitch will simply be (`width` * `bpp`), aligned to some boundary. For example, if the `bpp` is 3 (bytes per pixel), and the width is 9, you get 27. That's not a nice row number for many computers, so they'll often align that up to the nearest multiple of 4. Thus the pitch you would see in most images is 28.

So to compute the alignment, simply compute the largest power of two (up to 8) that divides into the pitch. If the pitch in the image is 28, the largest power of two is 4. Set that to `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT`. Generally, you can stop at 4, because that's the largest alignment most images will use.

The times when you *need* to use `GL_ROW_LENGTH` are when the computed pitch (`align(width * bpp, alignment)`) does not equal the actual pitch. If that happens, then you need to use both the alignment and the row length. But this is such a rare occurrence that you should probably just discard any image that uses such a wildly incorrect pitch.

Answer (score -1):

`GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` is the byte-offset of where the first pixel in a row starts in an image.  Setting it to one is almost always the safe bet (i.e., it works with almost every image type [and it's never not worked for me]).

The default value is four, which works fine for RGBA images, but fails miserably for RGB images (you'll know instantly when you see the image - it'll look like a set of diagonal bands).

Comment: I know that 1 will do most of the time, but I am interested in how to do it properly, even when the image library returns some unusual values for pitch.

Comment: It's effectively the number of bytes in a single component of a pixels.  So, for example, if you have `unsigned short` components for a `GL_RGB` pixel rectangle, you'd set the `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` to 2 (`sizeof(GLushort)`).

Comment: -1: No, setting it to 1 is not "almost always" correct. If the image format uses a row alignment of 4 bytes (and some do), and you try to store an RGB image with an odd width, then you'll screw up your padding. Also, it is not "the byte-offset of where the first pixel in a row starts in an image"; it is the byte *alignment* for each row of pixels. That is, a row will be padded out to that alignment.

Comment: Indeed, I should have said "alignment" as compared to "byte-offset".  Your points are valid, so I accept your view.  That said, in my experience of helping folks, setting the unpack alignment to one has corrected vastly more errors than it create.