# How to calculate pitch of an image Visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, cuda

I want to calculate the pitch of an input decoded video frame. Is there any formulae to do it. I am at the moment getting the pitch from creating a decoder and calling the CUDA function of mapping decoder. 
BUt by main question is can I calculate the pitch of an image directly using width and height ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pitch or widthstep (in bytes) is usually some convenient multiple of 128 bytes, like 512 or 1024. It's obviously going to be wider than the image itself, so it must be at least **image_width (in no. of elements)** x **element_size (in bytes)**.

It will be the next available pitch, so if your image is 511 char elements wide, it should be 512 bytes. But of course the padding requirements are dependent on the way the image was created in device memory.

Answer (score 1):

At its most basic you can use `width * bpp`  so if you have a 500 wide image at 3 bytes per pixel you have a pitch of 1500.

Note:

This does not take into account padding or ensuring a multiple of 2 for the pitch.

[Given the pitch of an image, how to calculate the GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052463/given-the-pitch-of-an-image-how-to-calculate-the-gl-unpack-alignment)  is good for reference too.