# Load png image for embedded system

Tags: c++, image, embedded, png

I am working on a embedded deep learning inference C++ project using tensorRT.
For my model it is necessary to subtract the mean image.

The api that I'm using allows me to define a mean image with the following data structure for rgb images:

```
uint8_t *data[DW_MAX_IMAGE_PLANES];       // raw image data 
size_t pitch;                             // pitch of the image in bytes
uint32_t height;                          // height of the image in px
uint32_t width;                           // image width in px
uint32_t planeCount;                      // plane count of the image
```

So far I found the lib LodePNG, which is quite usefull for this task I think.
It can load pngs with just a few lines:

```
// Load file and decode image.
std::vector<unsigned char> image;
unsigned width, height;
unsigned error = lodepng::decode(image, width, height, filename);
```

The question now is how to convert `std::vector<unsigned char>` to `uint8_t *[DW_MAX_IMAGE_PLANES]` and calculate the pitch and planeCount values?

As I'm using rgb images DW_MAX_IMAGE_PLANES equals 3.

Comment: The title of your question seems kinda wrong, since you loaded the png already successfully.

Comment: Perhaps a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) reference might be useful? There are a few ways to get a pointer to the data managed by the vector, including (but not limited to) getting a pointer to its first element.

Comment: As for the rest, doesn't the library you have supply you with that meta-data?

Comment: Using reinterpret_cast as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254615/how-to-cast-vectorunsigned-char-to-char Just make sure, that unsigned char and uint8_t are of the same size.

Comment: @MarekVitek On a platform where `uint8_t` exists, it's extremely unlikely that it's not the same as `unsigned char`. If `char` is not 8 bits then there can't really be an `int8_t` type.

Comment: You mean like on the platforms, where char is 7bit? :-) Never say never. But you are right, this is highly unlikely and on modern platforms size is same.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude no LodePNG does not supplay any planeCount or pitch values.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I agree about `uint8_t`, but `int8_t` could be a different type than `signed char`. **In theory**. Practically, I have yet to find such a system and I don't think it makes much sense.

Comment: Please notice: I have updated the expected format for the raw data: it is now uint8_t *data[DW_MAX_IMAGE_PLANES]

Comment: Question how to calculate pitch has already [been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041509/how-to-calculate-pitch-of-an-image-visual-studio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values for `pitch` and `planeCount` are simple. Since LodePNG's `decode` defaults to `bitdepth = 8`, the value of `pitch`, in bytes, is `1`. And because the image is RGB, the value of `planeCount` is `3`--one plane for each color.

Since you are not using the alpha channel, you should probably have LodePNG simply decode into RGB format directly:

```
unsigned error = lodepng::decode(image, width, height, filename, LCT_RGB);
```

But once the image is decoded into the `std::vector<unsigned char>`, you will not be able to use it directly. The decoded data from LodePNG is in the following format:

```
image -> R0, G0, B0, R1, G1, B1, R2, G2, B2, ...
```

But you need it in the following format:

```
data[0] -> R0, R1, R2, ...
data[1] -> G0, G1, G2, ...
data[2] -> B0, B1, B2, ...
```

If you are memory constrained, you'll have to rearrange the values in the image vector `(R0, R1, ... Rn, G0, G1, ... Gn, B0, B1, ... Bn)` and calculate the appropriate pointers to initialize the `data` array.

If you have available memory, you can create separate vectors for each of the three color channels. Then copy the data from the decoded `image` and initialize the `data` array with pointers to the first element of the vectors.